# web.xml error-page 404 error path

Tags: java, spring, http-status-code-404, web.xml

I've the following web.xml:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
</error-page>
```

When I go to `localhost:port/myapplication/someincorrecturl` it properly redirects me to index.html file. But when I go to `localhost:port/myapplication/someincorrecturl1/someincorrecturl2` the application gives me a 404 error. How can I solve the problem for any incorrect URL with more than one path?

Comment: I have the same problem,  may i know how you resolved it

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed your application on Tomcat and you are just typing localhost or localhost:port it won't redirect to your application.

You can access by typing localhost:port/YourProjectName. It is root of your project and if you want to access any other resource you can access it by localhost:port/YourProjectName/OtherResource. If OtherResource is not present and you have mapped 404 error with index.jsp it will redirect it to index.jsp.

You are giving both root and subpath wrongly.

Comment: Correct I forget to put application in my question. I just edited it.

Comment: add it in web.xml <display-name> Project Name</display-name>, are you facing same issue now ?

Comment: @sajid I have the same issue, could you help me